# roscore doesnt start

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I start to run the roscore on ROS hydro, and I get this error :

```
WARNING: disk usage in log directory [/home/astro/.ros/log] is over 1GB.
It's recommended that you use the 'rosclean' command.

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/roscore", line 63, in <module>
    roslaunch.main(['roscore', '--core'] + sys.argv[1:])

  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 279, in main
    p.start()

  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()

  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 215, in _start_infrastructure
    self._start_server()

  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 166, in _start_server
    self.server.start()

  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 368, in start
    code, msg, val = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(self.uri).get_pid()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

What is wrong ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208225/roscore-doesnt-start/) by [Hkev68](https://answers.ros.org/users/22313/hkev68/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-04-30**:
This is a warning which says that your log storage is more than 1 GB.. If you want, you can just run rosclean as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As warned logs are over 1GB

use `rosclean purge` to remove logs. check [rosclean](http://wiki.ros.org/rosclean)

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1